# Keep showing keyboard when press keyboards submit button

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-textinput

I want to keep showing keyboard. For example, when I press submit, the process takes place and the keyboard remains open.

```js
<TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={(text) => SetText(text)}
        onSubmitEditing={() => press(text)}
      />
```

Like sending messages in whatsapp. It's kind of the opposite of keyboard.dismiss().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextInput` component from react-native has a property specifically for that - `blurOnSubmit`:

```
<TextInput blurOnSubmit={false} {...yourOtherProps} />
```

You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/textinput.md#bluronsubmit